# Ubuntu 16.10: My third monitor becomes displays noisy after waking up

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, suspend

**My configuration:**

- A Lenovo T450s
- Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) graphic card. `lspci` result: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
- Ubuntu 16.10 64bit
- GNOME Shell 3.20.4
- xserver-xorg version 1:7.7+13ubuntu4
- I have connected two Dell P2317H monitors using my docking station. One of them is connected by vga port and another one with hdmi port to the docking station.

**My Problem:**

When my laptop goes to sleep and after a while when I wake it up, sometimes the vga connected monitor displays everything noisy and flickering.

Any idea how to solve or investigate this problem?

Comment: does `alt+F2`, then `r` help? i.e. `gnome-shell` restart

Comment: No, it didn't fix the problem. If I turn off that monitor and turn it on again, it will be fixed most of the times.